# How to change the label of bar chart in Extjs5?

Tags: javascript, extjs, charts, extjs5

This is something about the ExtJs5 charts.I have trouble changing the bar chart's labels.

Codes is as below:

```
Ext.create('Ext.chart.CartesianChart', {
        store: {
            fields: ['pet', 'households', 'total'],
            data: [{
                pet: {name:'Cats'},
                households: 38,
                total: 93
            }]
        },
        axes: [{
            type: 'numeric',
            position: 'left'
        }, {
            type: 'category',
            position: 'bottom'
        }],
        series: [{
            type: 'bar',
            xField: 'pet',
            yField: 'households',
            label:{
                field:'pet',
                renderer:function(pet){
                    return 'Dear '+pet.name;
                }
            }
        }]
    });
```

You must have noticed that the field 'pet' is an object instead of a string.
The **renderer** in the **series label** returns the value I want it to be,but the label is still [object Object]!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Labels under the category(x axis in your code) are rendered by 'category' not the series.Try code below:

```
{
   type: 'category',
   position: 'bottom',
   renderer:function(label){
     return label.name;//the var 'label' represents the pet object.
   }
}
```

By the way,I found another problem. No matter how many models are there in the chart store,only the first bar is displayed!